# What are good naming conventions for an ASP.net solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've created a solution which includes projects for an asp.net mvc website that also includes a service. And, I'm now trying to think of good names for the data projects to make it clear that one relates to the data for the service and one, the data for the website.

In general does anyone have a good pointer for project names for this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application name set as a solution name. In solution Create Folder Like Web,Service,Push Notification, SharedLibraries, WindowService. in Web You can add Multiple Web Site and Web Application, In SharedLibraries you can Add common and 3rd party Library and Console application. In Service folder you can add multiple Web service application.
For naming use Type of Project For Web application, ApplicationName_Web, For Service ApplicationName_Service, Business Layer Library ApplicationName_Data e.t.c.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can apply also Microsoft - Naming Guidelines - [Names of Assemblies and DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-assemblies-and-dlls).